# when is the size of a pointer equals 2 bytes not 4 in C?

Tags: c, pointers, size

```
int* p;
printf("%d", sizeof(p));
```

The answer would be 4 bytes!
I am using C

How to declare a pointer of a size (2 byte)? Does it depend on the compiler? As far as I know, C and ansi C are the same .. would this differ in ansi C?

Comment: It's platform dependent.

Comment: The proper way to print that in modern C is `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (int *));`, the type of `sizeof`'s return value is not `int`.

Comment: The real question here is: why do you (think you) need a 2 bytes size pointer?

Comment: You can declare a 16 bit pointer using a `8086` paltform and declare a `near` pointer ;)

Comment: @LPs: Indeed you can: +32767

Comment: @LPs, well,its an assignment. I am given a binary file for directory , i am trying to create a structure to represent it, but all the pointers should be 2 bytes

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the assignment: probably you need a `uint16_t*`/`int16_t*`/`short*`/`unsigned short*` to point a 2 bytes variable. But the pointer size is platform dependant. Otherwise if you declare, e.g., `uint16_t *temp;` with `uint16_t temp2 = *temp;`  will give back the value of a pointed 16 bits variable.

Comment: If you have to use 2 byte pointer, you actually need an "offset". You can have a "base" 32 bit pointer to point to a base address, and use 16 bit "offset" to add to it. This way you effectively create a 16 bit memory space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard intentionally doesn't specify sizes for pointers.

It *even* allows for pointer sizes to be different for different types: `sizeof(type1*)` is not necessarily the same as `sizeof(type2*)`!

This allows for C to target the most regular to the most exotic architectures.

Lastly, your program behaviour is *undefined*: you should use `%zu` as the formatter for a `sizeof` return. (Note that `sizeof(p)` *is* defined despite `p` being uninitialised - that's because `sizeof(p)` is evaluated at *compile* time.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe are you using Turbo C compiler?

Size of pointer and int is 2 bytes in Turbo C compiler on windows 32 bit machine. So size of pointer is compiler specific. But generally most of the compilers are implemented to support 4 byte pointer variable in 32 bit and 8 byte pointer variable in 64 bit machine